# Shell : logical ANDs and ORs instead of if-else

Tags: bash, shell, unix, boolean, zsh

I was wondering why

```
i=10
  if [ $i -lt 5 ]; then
    echo "$i < 5"
elif [ $i -gt 5 ]; then
    echo "$i > 5"
elif [ $i -eq 5 ]; then
    echo "$i = 5"
fi
```

Outputs proper result:

```
10 > 5
```

Whereas

```
i=10
     [ $i -lt 5 ] && {
    echo "$i < 5"
} || [ $i -gt 5 ] && {
    echo "$i > 5"
} || [ $i -eq 5 ] && {
    echo "$i = 5"
}
```

behaves an unusual way:

```
10 > 5
10 = 5
```

In my opinion, as the interpreter seeks for `1`s, it should work like this:

> 0 && {} || 1 && {} || 0 && {}
>
> 0 so the 0 && {} is definitely 0; skip `{}`
>
> 1 means that {} must be checked to define the value of whole `1 && {}`

So that the result is 1, but the only `{}` is executed stays after `1`.
However, this all does work as it should when I put `! {` instead of `{`s.

```
i=10
     [ $i -lt 5 ] && ! {
    echo "$i < 5"
} || [ $i -gt 5 ] && ! {
    echo "$i > 5"
} || [ $i -eq 5 ] && ! {
    echo "$i = 5"
}
```

WHY?! I thought it seeks for `1`s so since it finds a `0` in a `&&` it doesn't look at other expressions in the chain!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The {...} does not make a difference, so what you have is equivalent to this:

```
i=10
[ $i -lt 5 ] && 
echo "$i < 5" ||
[ $i -gt 5 ] &&
echo "$i > 5" || 
[ $i -eq 5 ] &&
echo "$i = 5"
```

And the way this works is:

1. `[ $i -lt 5 ]`: This is false (returns failure), so it jumps to the next `||`, which has `[ $i -gt 5 ]` following it.
2. `[ $i -gt 5 ]`: This is true (returns success), so it jumps to the next `&&`, which has `echo "$i > 5"` following it.
3. `echo "$i > 5"`: This returns success, so it jumps to the next `&&`, which has `echo "$i = 5"` following it.
4. `echo "$i = 5"`: This returns success, so it jumps to... wait no, there's a newline. We're done.

`&&` and `||` are called short-circuit operators.

EDIT: To stress the point further,

```
A && B || C
```

is **NOT** the same as

```
if A; then
    B
else
    C
fi
```

It's equivalent to

```
if A; then
    if ! B; then
        C
    fi
else
    C
fi
```

Comment: And more specifically in the shell `X && Y || Z` is **not** a ternary operation.

Comment: Why does it jump from `1` to the second expression in the next multiplication (step 3)?

Comment: @theoden, When the command succeeds, it jumps to the next `&&`. When the command fails, it jumps to the next `||`. It's that simple. `echo` returns 0 (success), so it jumps to the next `&&`. And as @EtanReisner mentioned, `a && b || c` is **not** the same as `if a; then b; else c; fi`

Comment: @geirha, damn i thought it was a bit more complicated, like it creates an ordered binary tree and parses from left to right (from top to bottom).
I thought `X && Y || Z` means the same as `X * Y + Z`.

EDIT: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`&&` and `||` are evaluated from left to right.  Your command is more or less equivalent to this:

```
(((( false && { echo 1; true; } ) || true ) && { echo 2; true; } ) || false ) && { echo 3; true; }
```

- `false && { echo 1; true; }` doesn't print anything, and evaluates to `false`
- `false || true` evaluates to `true`
- `true && { echo 2; true; }` prints `2` and evaluates to `true`
- `true || false` evaluates to `true`
- `true && { echo 3; true; }` prints `3` and evaluates to `true`.

Mystery solved.

Comment: Wait, It is right arithmetically, but why is it
A * B + C * D becomes (((A * B) + C) * D)?

Comment: @theoden Because these are list operators, and according to the `bash` manual: "[o]f these list operators, `&&` and `||` have equal precedence, followed by `;` and `&`, which have equal precedence".  Meaning, if you only have `&&` and `||`, they are evaluated strictly from left to right.